# Horrible quality on 360 image

Tags: aframe

I’m using a Ricoh Theta V camera to take 360 degree images to display in A-frame, but the quality on these images when displayed is horrible. I’ve tried different settings on the camera but it does not really get any better. The images have resolution: 5376x2688, which is then resized to 4096x2048. Is this a camera issue? Do I need a higher resolution, or is there something I can do in A-frame?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. It might be better on [photography.se] or a more design-oriented site.

Comment: @cHao That depends solely on the solution to the issue. If the solution is adjusting attributes in a-frame, it's a programming question.

Comment: If you believe this to be a programming question, then it's incomplete. Programming questions involve code. We'd need to see that in order to see what (if anything) you're doing wrong.

Comment: try downscaling them in photoshop / gimp, so that aframe doesn't have to do it for you. Also check the images with a normal image viewer whether they are blurry by themselves

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I'll try that! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Textures need to be sized to powers of 2 in WebGL. So 4096x2048 is appropriate, perhaps better quality to pre-resize it. Though Ricoh Theta images are already low-res/blurry in the first place.

Comment: Ah, alright. I'll look into another camera then. Thank you!